# Revert to my original IP address after using a free VPN

Tags: networking, firefox, internet, vpn

I used a free VPN (Windscribe) EXTENSION to Firefox which changed my IP address from New Zealand to an IP address in Hong Kong.  My Internet speeds slowed down so badly that I disabled and removed the Firefox extension.
The problem is that the Hong Kong IP address seems to persist and my internet speeds are so slooow that Firefox bombs out with a timeout issue.

How can I revert to my origininal New Zealand IP address and stop this slooow internet access ?

Comment: Are you sure you removed the extension? Did you check your IP address anywhere?

Comment: @JoKeR   If went into Firefox and disabled the extension and then removed the extension.  My IP address remains in Hong Kong (27.122.nn.nnn) despite many re-boots.  When I boot into Windows10, my IP address shows as New Zealand (222.154.nn.nnn). I have used "whatismyipaddress.com/ip-lookup" to get my IP address in both Ubuntu and Windows.

Comment: did you install it on all browsers? open other browser or launch yours with extensions disabled and see the result.

Comment: @JoKeR - I only installed it on Firefox. I tried whatismyipaddress on BRAVE, but got the same Hong Kong IP address as with Firefox. I have Disconnected Winscribe, then I Disabled Winscribe on Firefox, closed both Firefox and Brave. I then re-opened Firefox and my IP address is still the Hong Kong  address. I will close Firefox, reboot my PC and check again.

Comment: what is your system IP? check it in terminal `curl ifconfig.me`

Comment: My system IP is still the HK IP 27.122.nn.nnn (i.e. the same as my Public IP address).

Comment: Did you install other software to the system? that means you have installed vpn or proxy and applied it to the system. You have to find what you have installed.

Comment: @JoKeR - I only installed the Winscribe extension to Firefox.  In Firefox I had the option to Disconnect and to Disable Winscribe.

Comment: browser extension does not apply IP system wide, that means you have installed something else

Comment: @JoKeR   I decided that I had nothing to lose so I loaded the Windscribe EXE and fully installed it - then I executed Windscribe from the Ubuntu Terminal and then Disconnected Windscribe from there.

This has resolved my Public IP issue.
Thank you for your assistance and for bearing with me in this journey !!

Comment: There's Windscribe for Ubuntu, you are talking about Windows version. I assume you installed it through Wine. That's not the correct way.

Answer (score -1):

I decided that I had nothing to lose so I loaded the Windscribe EXE and fully installed it - then I executed Windscribe from the Ubuntu Terminal and then Disconnected Windscribe from there. This has resolved my Public IP issue. Thank you for your assistance and for bearing with me in this journey !!

Comment: `.exe` is Windows format that is not how you install software in Ubuntu.

Comment: I installed it in Ubuntu using TERMINAL following the process shown on the Windscribe site at windscribe.com/guides/linux and chose Ubuntu.  Forgive my lapse into Windows jargon !